Sci-fi movie about denying history and choosing a future job. Only one man know history
I am trying to remember this movie I saw, also I have tried Google search but maybe I can't really formulate the plot/keywords very well. There are a few things I remember:
I think that the story has a narrator. People live in a new established society in an enclosed city and they are watched. At some point of age they have to choose what they will be. A young man will choose to be a "memorist" or "historician" and gets taught by an old man who is the only one who remembers history. Eventually the young man took his newly born sibling on a bicycle and tries to run from the city.
I don't know which production it is but I think that probably it is an American production and also after the year 2000.

The movie you are searching is "The Giver" (2014) with Jeff Bridges.

In a seemingly perfect community, without war, pain, suffering, differences or choice, a young boy is chosen to learn from an elderly man about the true pain and pleasure of the "real" world.

The young student rides a bicycle, but and at some point he tries to run from the city.
Trailer here
